# Gingerbread Apps : HonyComb tablets

Tags: android

Is it possible to install android 2.3 based apps on tablets having honeycomb version? If not possible, any alternatives ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. It's just that the app will probably not look that good.

If it's your own app, I'd suggest you modify it to look and work properly on a tablet. 
You can have actionbars in pre-3.0 devices, using `http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html`

I have used that in a number of apps, it makes your app look like an ics app, even on Gingerbread devices. Also, it allows you to develop using the latest SDK, and still run your app on older devices.

If it's not your app, then you're stuck with an app that stretches its screens to tablet size.  Unfortunately, there's quite a few apps that look bad on my tablet.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, most 2.3 applications can be installed on honeycomb, with the exception of when they specify not to install on tablets within the manifest.

But just because it installs on a tablet doesn't mean it will look good either, if you don't scale anything to fit the larger screen size you will have a small active rectangle in the center of the tablet screen with black space everywhere else.

If you are looking on how to scale an application, most game engines are capable of auto scaling, such as [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/). Otherwise you have to get the screen size and density on runtime and scale everything on the screen proportionally.